# AdMob Test id working but Real id not working

Tags: android, admob

When i am using the AdMob Test ID it is working and showing the test add but when i am using my real id then no ads are been shown in the emulator  (in android studio)

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should only be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Real ads only showing when you make your **app live** in **play store**. So,if ads is coming in Test Id So,in real time ads is also come but you make your app live in play store.

I hope this can help You!

Thank You.